# Macro to export excel email IDs to outlook distribution list

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

Is there a way to write a macro that exports the email ID column from excel sheet to outlook distribution list?

I would ideally want to replace the old one with new distribution list every time, the macro is run.

The following is what I have been trying,

```
Public Sub DistributionList()

Dim objOutlook As New Outlook.Application
Dim objNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objDistList As Outlook.DistListItem
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objRecipients As Outlook.Recipients


Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objDistList = objOutlook.CreateItem(olDistributionListItem)
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set objRecipients = objMail.Recipients
objDistList.DLName = InputBox("Enter name of Distribution List")

For i = 1 To Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
objRecipients.Add (Range("C" & i).Value)
Next i

objDistList.AddMembers objRecipients
objDistList.Display
objRecipients.ResolveAll

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objNameSpace = Nothing
Set objDistList = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set objRecipients = Nothing

End Sub
```

But while running this, I am getting an error, user defined type not defined.

Can this be corrected or is there a better way to do this?

Can anybody help me in doing this? Thanks

Comment: have you added a reference to the Outlook library? (under Tools>References). That would explain your error.

Comment: @nwhaught After I did that it is working. But I have one question. This one is taking the email ID from the B column but it is displaying name also as email ID. Can we correct this code to take the name from the A column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user defined type not defined error almost always means that you've forgotten to add a reference. Go under tools>> references to add it. In your case you need the Outlook library.

To change which column it's finding the names, change

```
Range("C"
```

To refer to the column containing the names.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to do that. I have one more question. I want to loop through different teams and create different distribution lists for each team. I used the following code for the first team,

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$10").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "Team 1"
objDistList.DLName = "Team 1"

But I am not able to do it for the second team. Can you helping me in editing this code to loop through the teams?

Comment: If you are looking for a separate question,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354269/loop-through-different-filter-options-in-excel-macro