# loop through different filter options in Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am just wondering how to loop through different options in excel macro and perform the same operation.

My operation is to export IDs from excel to outlook distribution list.

I used the following code :

```
Public Sub DistributionList()
Dim objOutlook As New Outlook.Application
Dim objNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objDistList As Outlook.DistListItem
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objRecipients As Outlook.Recipients


Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objDistList = objOutlook.CreateItem(olDistributionListItem)
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set objRecipients = objMail.Recipients
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$10").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "Team 1"
objDistList.DLName = "Team 1"

For i = 2 To Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
objRecipients.Add (Range("B" & i).Value)
Next i

objDistList.AddMembers objRecipients
objDistList.Display
objRecipients.ResolveAll

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objNameSpace = Nothing
Set objDistList = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set objRecipients = Nothing

End Sub
```

In the above code these two lines filter one team and export to one distribution list,

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$10").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "Team 1"
objDistList.DLName = "Team 1"
```

I have three teams and I would want three distribution lists. Can anybody help me in editing this code so that it would loop through the file and create three distribution lists?

I am new to VBA and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub DistributionList()
Dim objOutlook As New Outlook.Application
Dim objNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objDistList As Outlook.DistListItem
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objRecipients As Outlook.Recipients
Dim i As Long, j as Long, teamNames() As String

'''The Team Names are Stored in array '''''''''
redim teamNames(1 to 3)
teamNames() = Split("Red,Green,Blue", ",")
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

For j = LBound(teamNames) To UBound(teamNames) 
    Set objDistList = objOutlook.CreateItem(olDistributionListItem)
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set objRecipients = objMail.Recipients

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$10").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
    teamNames(j)
    objDistList.DLName = teamNames(j)

    For i = 2 To Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        objRecipients.Add (Range("B" & i).Value)
    Next i

    objDistList.AddMembers objRecipients
    objDistList.Display
    objRecipients.ResolveAll
    Set objDistList = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set objRecipients = Nothing
next j

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objNameSpace = Nothing


End Sub
```

You can try out the above I think it should work but didn't try it out. You should have a way to select the Distribution list name from the range in the spreadsheet or through a userinput rather than just counting from 1-3 IMHO. It is up to you though.

Thanks

Comment: in this code, how can we pass the team names ?  I just gave the name as team 1 for test purpose. Ideally I have different text names for each team name. can we modify the code to give the name?

Comment: Sure where do you want to get the team name from the range you specified or somewhere else?

Comment: I dont want to get the names, I want to hardcode the names in the beginning so that we can use it from there.

Comment: What are the names then so I can put them in there?

Comment: Can we have it as Red, Blue and Green?

Comment: @SilentObserver I have added the team names to an array. I am not sure if this is working code so please test it and get back to me if it is not working. Thanks

Comment: Yes you can make it the entire spreadsheet by setting the range as the used range so it will pick up all rows and columns that have any data. For example if there is data in "A1:D100" and also some data in D101 but no data in C101 B101 or A101; using UsedRange will create a Range with an address "A1:D101". Not sure if that is what you want but it is typically what is done.

Comment: @ClintStreet Thanks for the help. It is working fine. I have one more doubt. This one explicitly opens the outlook and we need to manually save it. Is there a way we can make the process to happen in background via macros? Instead of opening and saving it, it automatically opens and saves it in background?

Comment: That is good that it is working I will see if I can try it out and get it to save without displaying. I will try to do it a bit later.