# Filter a column and select the last used row

Tags: vba, excel

I want to filter a particular column in Excel sheet and then select the range of it until the last used row.

For getting a particular column I am using

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D30").AutoFilter Field:=3 , Criteria1:= "1"
```

And for finding the last row I am using

```
Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
```

I am not able to combine both together. If I run both the commands together, I am getting the entire results instead of filtered results.

I know it may be a simple one, But I am not able to do it. Can anybody help me in doing it?

My requirement is that the first the column should be filtered and then the range of until the last unused row should be selected. So that I can do some commands using the selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `SpecialCells` Method with the `xlCellTypeVisible` argument. I also qualified the worksheet to work with, since it's way more stable than using `ActiveSheet` (should always be avoided, unless **absolutely** necessary.)

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("mySheet") 'change to the sheet name you need

Dim lRow as Long
lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("$A$1:$D" & lRow).AutoFilter Field:=3 , Criteria1:= "1"

Dim rRng as Range, cel as Range
Set rRng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'assumes header row in column 1

'Updated code based on your comments.
For each cel in rRng
   objRecipients.Add cel
Next

ws.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D30").AutoFilter Field:=3 , Criteria1:= "1" In this command, A1-d30 is the range which I gave to manually check. I want to check for the entire sheet. That is what I was asking

Comment: I am using the following command,

for i=1 to cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
objRecipients.Add (Range("B" & i).Value)
Next i

Now I want to add only for the filtered values. That is my requirement. Can you modify this and help me?

Comment: see update. Assumes you still want to use column D as your last column. You can change that easily, and also change the column you use the capture the last row of data, by adjusting the column argument in `lRow`

Comment: I have given the command which I am using for the complete one. Now I want to use the same command for filtered version.

Comment: see my answer now. It would have been better to include your whole code in your OP, but it's okay, it was easy enough.

Comment: I am getting an error in Set rRng line as "No Cells found". Can you look into it?

Comment: is your `ActiveSheet` what you suspect? Does your filter return the results you expect? Does your data have a reader (as I commented)?

Comment: It was my mistake. Now it is working fine. Can we modify the code to remove the filter at the end of the loop?

Comment: see my updated code. also, please mark the answer if it worked for you. Lastly, please post all your relevant code in your OP next time, to avoid all the back-and-forth on the comments :)

Comment: i am getting an error in the ws.AutoFilterMode =False as "Object Variable or With Block variable not set"

Comment: did you use this statement `Set ws = Sheets("mySheet")`? If not, you can say `ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False` and see my comments about qualifying the sheets in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried to post the entire requirement in another occasion. But I was told I must not post it entirely and expect an answer. That was the reason I thought I can try it step by step. Thanks a lot for your help. Much appreciated.!!

Comment: yes, it's a balance of only posting what is needed and relevant, but not everything :) Best to you.

Comment: I tried those.. Still I am getting error in that line. Trying to modify that. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: This is our original requirement, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354269/loop-through-different-filter-options-in-excel-macro/33356083#33356083 

My friend posted this. If you can, please have a look at it.

Comment: You have a nice solution there as an answer. Do you need more help with that? If so, ask the person who answered, so he can adjust the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
With Range("A1:D" & Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row)
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1"
    .Resize(, 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
End With
```

Comment: I am using the following command, for i=1 to cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row objRecipients.Add (Range("B" & i).Value) Next i Now I want to add only for the filtered values. That is my requirement. Can you modify this and help me?